# Copy-initialization with implicit conversion in c++

Tags: c++, initialization

```
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo(float b) {}
};

class Bar {
  public:
    Bar(Foo foo) {}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Bar b1(3.0f);  // accept, one implicit convertion happens there.
    Bar b2 = 3.0f;  // error: no viable conversion from 'float' to 'Bar'
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the second expression fail to compile? I expected that it would call the same converting constructor as same as the first expression.

Comment: Try changing `Bar(Foo foo)` to `Bar(const Foo &foo)`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Why did you think it will work (it does not)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [dcl.init]:

> Otherwise (i.e., for the remaining copy-initialization cases), user-defined conversion sequences
>   that can convert **from the source type to the destination type** or (when a conversion function
>   is used) to a derived class thereof are enumerated as described in 13.3.1.4, and the best one is
>   chosen through overload resolution (13.3).

We can invoke a user-defined conversion that is from the source type *directly* to the target type. That is, if we had `Bar(float )`, we would consider that constructor. However, in this case, our candidate is simply `Bar(Foo )`, which does not take a `float`.

You are allowed zero or one user-defined conversion. In the direct-initialization case, we simply call `Bar(Foo )` which invokes one user-defined conversion (`float --> Foo`). In the copy-initialization case, we are looking for a conversion sequence from `float` (the source type) all the way to `Bar` (the destination type), which would involve *two* user-defined conversions (`float --> Foo`, `Foo --> Bar`), hence the error.

Comment: When the standard says "user-defined conversion sequences" what precisely counts. For instance the standard specifies things like narrowing conversions directly in the text of the standard. But what about things like conversions defined in the standard library? You don't normally say these are "user-defined" and I guess there are restrictions about what the user can do in namespace std.

Comment: @ChrisBeck User-defined conversions are those conversions specified by either constructors (e.g. `Bar(Foo );`) or conversion functions (e.g. `operator Foo();`).

Comment: Barry: yeah I'm looking now in 12.3.1, it doesn't mention any different treatment for standard library so I guess those count as "user-defined" for these purposes

Comment: @ChrisBeck You can also check out clause 4 - it enumerates all of the "standard conversions."

Answer (score 4):

The second type of initialization is called copy-initialization and uses copy constructor. Therefore, this type of initialization expects the right side is convertible to Bar.